# What test do I use / how do I show in the analysis that I measured everyone twice?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, spss, repeated-measures

I have already asked a [question on this forum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12453/what-test-do-i-use-in-order-to-analyze-a-within-participants-repeated-measure-exp) about this, but as I changed my experiment a bit and I am still confused.

I conducted an experiment in which 25 men and 25 women listened to an attractive conversation and picked a photo (between a woman with red and a woman with green shirt) and next, they heard a neutral dialogue and did exactly the same, picked a photo between an woman in red and a woman in green. My hypothesis is that men are much more attracted to women in red, in contrast to women. I was thinking of using repeated measures ANOVA as both men and women were 'examined' in the same experimental conditions. So, I guess that my columns are: `gender` 2 levels (0 for males and 1 for females), `attraction` 2 levels (0 for no and 1 for yes) and `color` 2 levels (0 for green-or no red and 1 for red).

My problem is how do I show that each participant did this twice (i.e., there were two dialogues)?  (*Note: I am using SPSS.*)

Comment: It sounds like you don't know many things about ANOVA, either. This is not a problem but you should go the extra mile and get a statistics text book and read it. Especially since it is important to you you probably (hehe) wouldn't want some random internet bozo from a forum mess up your research. Statistics isn't that hard from a user's perspective. And it's cool and interesting. Learning about it is totally worth it and it might even make your research more sound if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @xmjx you're right! I should buy a book, actually I will as I really need it. But I would really be grateful if you told me whether I'm completely wrong about ANOVA or any comment on what I've written above. I don't ask for an answer but for some help towards the right direction. Thank you anyway, I really know that what you've said is what I should do.

Comment: If you compare responses between men and women, this is definitely not a repeated measures setup. Repeated measures would require that you measure each individual twice: once for some baseline (e.g. "normal") and one for a stimulus (e.g. "attractive").

Comment: Actually, that's what I do! Each of my participants (both males and females are measured twice (attractive dialogue and one pair of photos and then unattractive dialogue and one pair of photos)

Comment: What about loglinear analysis?? :S

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misread your question.

Answer (score 4):

You find yourself in a common case where you have measured a certain outcome in response to various parameters.
This can be analysed using a generalized linear model, a fairly wide category of statistical models (that, for instance, also include ANOVA). This types of model will create a linear relationship between your output and the variables (regressors).

In this case, as the outcome is discrete, I would use a logistic regression; as you measured the same subject twice we will have to use a mixed effect  (repeated measures) logistic model, including the subject as a random effect

I'm sorry, but I don't know anything about SPSS, so I will give you an example in R.

Let's make some mock data:

```
# Make data reproducible
set.seed(51280)
# number of the experimental subject 
subject <- rep(1:20, each=2)
# 10 men, 10 women (twice, as you did two trials)
gender <- rep(c("M", "F"), each=40)
# 1: attractive dialog, 0 neutral dialog
trial <- rep(1:0, 40)
# outcome: red or green, I'm sampling it randomly here
outcome <- sample(c("red", "green"), 40, replace=TRUE)

data <- data.frame(subject, gender, trial, outcome)
```

`data` will look something like (first 10 rows only):

```
   subject gender trial outcome
1        1      M     0   green
2        1      M     1   green
3        2      M     0   green
4        2      M     1     red
5        3      M     0   green
6        3      M     1   green
7        4      M     0     red
8        4      M     1     red
9        5      M     0     red
10       5      M     1     red
```

If we inspect the data using `table` we get

```
> table(data$outcome,data$gender)

         F  M
  green 19 19
  red   21 21

> table(data$outcome,data$trial)

         0  1
  green 24 14
  red   16 26
```

Now we can use the `lmer` (linear mixed model) function of the `lme4` package to generate a model which linearly connects our outcome (red/green) with the regressors (sex and trial), considering the nuisance factor (subject). We use the formula `outcome ~ gender * trial` which tells `glm` to use `outcome` as the independent variable and gender and trial as regressors, counting their interactions. We don't just want to know if `outcome` is different between men and women and between the two trials (case in which we would use `+` instead of `*`), we want to know if it is different when the two factors are considered together.

```
require(lme4)
logit.model <- glmer(outcome ~ gender * trial + (trial | subject), data,
                    family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

Finally, `summary(logit.model)` will tell us that in this case there are no differences in the outcome (as expected from random data).

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by the Laplace approximation 
Formula: outcome ~ gender * trial + (trial | subject) 
   Data: data 
  AIC   BIC logLik deviance
 60.5 77.17 -23.25     46.5
Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr   
 subject (Intercept) 2301.2   47.971          
         trial       4464.4   66.816   -0.675 
Number of obs: 80, groups: subject, 20

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -1.108e+01  1.733e+01  -0.640    0.523
genderM       -5.001e-06  8.240e+00   0.000    1.000
trial          2.244e+01  2.557e+01   0.878    0.380
genderM:trial -2.156e-04  1.218e+01   0.000    1.000

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) gendrM trial 
genderM     -0.238              
trial       -0.667  0.161       
genderM:trl  0.161 -0.677 -0.238
```

Comment: Thank you very much @nico! So, you suggest logistic regression?Iam a bit confused! I read this chapter and it gives an example about between subject groups, whereas my participants participated in the same experimental conditions!

Comment: Rethinking about my answer, it should probably be updated to consider repeated measures. It can be done with the `lmer` function in R, I'll update the answer, stay tuned :)

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! Much appreciated! :)

Comment: Although this approach is preferable, there are plenty who would just throw a mixed ANOVA at this situation and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

In Information Retrieval research, an experiment is often repeated several times (in system-oriented IR e.g. about 50 times with slightly varying data). In that case the solution is normally to establish some measure of central tendency (e.g. arithmetic mean) and do the significance test on that. Your population is human beings so you would want to come up with a measure for a single human being, which, in your case, could be the mean answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just checked loglinear analysis and chi square and realised that I can't use them as they demand different participants for each condition! And I am again completely confused! I thought of repeated measures logistic regression but I can't find more details! Any idea? Thank you again!